# Error: GCC parenthesized initializer in array new

Tags: c++

In template class constructor,initialize a array by `T *p = new T[10](userInputData)`
But the G++ `parenthesized initializer in array new`, how to deal with it?

Comment: Parenthesized initializer should never be used in modern C++. And it is certainly not suitable for array initializaiton.

Comment: @user7860670 That's a very strong statement. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that

> although we can use empty parentheses to **value initialize** the elements of an array, we **cannot supply an element initializer** inside the parentheses.

This means,

```
int *pia2 = new int[10](); //VALID, block of 10 ints value initialized to 0
int *pia3 = new int[10](55); //NOT VALID
```

For the same reason you're getting the mentioned error. In particular, you've supplied the **initializer** `userInputData`.

To **solve** this error you have to remove the initializer  `userInputData`. Also you can use [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) as shown below.

```
T *p = new T[10];
std::fill_n(p, 10, userInputData);
```

Comment: Removing the initializer will make the error go away, but leave OP with value initialized array, which doesn't seem to be what they want.

Comment: @super added `std::fill_n`.